# Cannot create Liferay Plugin Project: "Type [unknown] not present"

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-ide

When I'm trying to create a new Liferay Project (File > New > Liferay Plugin Project) I'm getting this error from Eclipse:

[image: Problem Opening Wizard]

My configurations are:

- Windows 7
- Java 1.6.0_45
- Eclipse Luna
- Liferay 6.2

And I also tried *New Liferay Project* shortcut button which is on the Eclipse toolbar but didn't work either.

I followed [this tutorial](http://tirthalpatel.blogspot.com.tr/2014/02/liferay-portal-6.2-development-setup-guide.html) to set up Liferay on my local system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds very much like a problem with your Liferay-IDE setup. I've not seen it and you might want to either update it (through your standard eclipse plugin update mechanism) or if you don't want to do this on the currently (otherwise) working installation, just download&install a separate version of Liferay IDE.

Eclipse and Liferay-IDE work just fine with any number of parallel installations - you just unzip to a different location and start that version. Preferably you should point to a new workspace (not to the old one) and create a Liferay server as well as a plugin there.

It might be overly complex to consider "reinstallation" when it's just a missing component in your installation, but as a remote recommendation it's probably easier than to debug your installation from here to figure out what's actually missing and where to get it from.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. I spent time trying to fix it to no avail. So you just have to use the `create.bat` file in the `liferay\liferay-plugins\portlets` directory

Usage is

`create.bat your-appname "Your AppName"` (portlet id, display name)

Then you can import the created project into Eclipse.

If you want to create a hook or theme you can find the `create.bat` files in the corresponding directories

Usage is explained [here](https://www.liferay.com/en_GB/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/creating-a-portlet) in detail

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @steven35. But this time it says " 'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: You need to add a SYSTEM variable for %ANT_HOME%. It has to point to the directory that contains your ant download. So for example `C:\apache-ant\apache-ant`

Comment: Here is an example of how to do it https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/820-7054/gicjc/index.html

Comment: However I'm not using Ant to build my project, so is there any way to do it with Maven?

Comment: you can create liferay portlet by using 'mvn archetype:generate' . you can find many blogs and tutorials on it.

Comment: Actually I've tried ant build as you said but it freezes when trying to load settings from ivy-settings.xml file. @steven35